# Terraform resource aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment and sensitive data

Tags: terraform

I have a beanstalk module that has a Terraform resource for aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment that loads env vars from a map.

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "default" {
  name                   = module.label.id
  ...
  ...
  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.env_vars
    content {
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
      name      = setting.key
      value     = setting.value
      resource  = ""
    }
  }
  ...
```

I also load secrets from the data source aws_secretsmanager_secret and pass them to the beanstalk module.

```
module "web-secrets" {
  source = "../modules/web/secrets" <- just loads secrets was data source aws_secrets_manager_secret
}

module "elastic-beanstalk-environment-lenz" {
  source                             = "../modules/beanstalk/beanstalk"
  ...
  ...

  env_vars = {
    "APPLICATION_NAME"        = "web"
    ...
    ...
    "API_KEY" = module.web-secrets.api_key
  }
}
```

however, during the terraform plan the aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment resource displays it's output on the screen.

```
terraform plan
      ...
      ...
      + setting {
          + name      = "API_KEY"
          + namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
          + value     = "password"
        }
      ...
```

As I am using Terraform cloud I can't attempt to use another utility in tfmask to hide the sensitive information before returning the output to the screen.

Comment: Normally you would just pass the name of your secret as env variable to the EB. Then in your app you would actually fetch the value of the secret.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I don't have the opportunity to have my devs fetch the secret from SSM just before the application launch unfortunately.